# Password requirement toggle modal in react native

Tags: react-native, user-interface, modal-dialog

Please how can I achieve this can of modal in react native?

[image]

If the user clicks on the black icon, the modal shows and when the user clicks on it again it disappears as it is in the first screenshot [image]

I have checked for some libraries but they are not giving what I want.

Comment: It will not disappear if you will change onRequestClose={() => {}} like this.

Comment: Which library is that? @HiteshPrajapati

Comment: https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a third party library that has onBackDropPress callback you can use

github.com/react-native-modal/react-native-modal

Answer (score 0):

dont use a library for this rather just use state.  If you have functional component you can do this

const [showInfo, setShowInfo] = useState(false)

then the black button on press has

onPress={() => setShowInfo(!showInfo)}

then the part of the text has this

{
showInfo && (
...your textviews go here
)
}

Comment: Yeah, I understand the state part but the Issue Is that the view to be shown is a Modal because it overlays the second text input. Now most of the Modal I have seen, when they show the background is not clickable anymore, hence the state does not change when clicking the toggle again. 

This is what am trying to solve, I don't know if there is any prop for this. I will appreciate a way forward from here  @Adam Katz

Comment: ahh sorry i misunderstood your problem, we use this modal at work
https://github.com/react-native-modal/react-native-modal
it has an onBackdropPress prop

Comment: thanks i made it an answer if you don't mind accepting that would be really rad :)